# Using Facebook api with Angular js $Routeprovider

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, angularjs-routing

I have been facing a issue from a long time.
I have been developing a web application using angular js (SPA) and i am also using facebook graph api.  I have used a facebook login button in the partials (Home-partial.html) and (contactus-partial.html). 
When i open the web application home-partial.html is loaded first and the facebook api works fine displaying the login/logout button. Now, when i route to contact us, the facebook buttons not appearing and also when i come back to home, the facebook button not appearing here also now.

Could any one please help me on this issue.

Regards,
Prateek Dhuper

Comment: This does not seem possible to solve without seeing a minimal code example reproducing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely using `FB.XFBML.parse()` will solve your problem: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

You need to use it for parsing Social Plugins generated after page load, which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, does FB.XFBML.parse() needs to be called whenever the partial is loaded through routing? @luschn

Comment: yeah, whenever you generate social plugins on the fly. check out the parameter though, you can also parse specific elements.

Comment: I guess`FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'))`  is what we can use when we need to parse the specific elements by passing the element id.

Comment: exactly, which is faster than parsing everything, of course

Comment: so should should i put `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo')) ` in partial.html inside  a `<script>` tag.

Comment: you can do that, or you can use it after loading the partial. it´s just important that it gets called when the button is loaded in the DOM.